# .Net UrlEncode an encrypted string

Tags: .net, encryption

Using C# .Net 4.0, I have a requirement to Encrypt a string (I use AesEncrypt) and then pass it on the query string.

As it's passed on the query string, I call a method to UrlEncode the string

HttpUtility.UrlEncode(paymentReference.AesEncrypt())

UrlEncode is encoding equal signs as you would expect (string to encode is '9/zAaohrc3oQLyTdplgxfg==') but then I Response.Redirect to the encoded url and the query string of the redirected page is unencoded and contains the equals signs again ....

Comment: I can't reproduce this - I get "12345678911%3d%3d".

Comment: I'd use UrlSafeBase64 encoding without padding on the ciphertext. That way you don't need to bother with UrlEncoding.

Comment: Jon, you are correct. Ill update my question. The issue seems to be when this encoded url is passed in Response.Redirect, it is no longer encoded